# Maximo Anywhere Multiple Failure Code Selection

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am using Maximo Anywhere 7.5.2 (Work Execution app). I need to select multiple FAILURE CODES instead of selecting Problem, Cause, Remedy.. The failure list should be multiselect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maximo doesn't support multiple failure codes (just the hierarchy of failure class->problem->cause->remedy. You can't support it in Anywhere without supporting it in Maximo.